# Calculating with pivot table in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2010

Really stupid question but can't seem to find an answer. I have a a worksheet with columns name, report, success. Name and report are text, success is 1 or 0.

I made a pivot table to summarize the results. Again three columns: Name, Number of reports (count of reports), Number of success (sum of success).

Now I want to have a success percentage. So sum of success divided by count of reports. How to do that, dynamically?

Comment: What version of Excel do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Would summarizing the success column by Average instead of Count solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by adding an extra column in the source data (fill, all values 1) and creating a calculated field (succes/ fill).

Comment: Yes that would work too - maybe easier with the Average in this case.

Comment: @lennart: I came up with the same method as you - strange that defining *fill =1* as a calculated field doesn't work the same. 
@assylias: agree `average` would be better assuming all report entries are non-blank

Comment: @lori_m yes, succes has to be either 0 or 1, not blank.